# Trouble Installing Vim 8.0

Tags: vim, installation

I followed the instructions at http://www.vim.org/git.php but got the following errors (after cloning the repo and running make in `vim/src`):

```
makefile:304: auto/config.mk: No such file or directory
makefile:2007: target `tags' given more than once in the same rule.
rm -f auto/config.cache
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\Users\Justin\DOCUME~1\MOBAXT~1\slash\bin\rm, rm -f auto/config.cache, ...) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
make: [auto/config.mk] Error 193 (ignored)
    if test "X" != "Xclean" \
            -a "X" != "Xdistclean" \
            -a "X" != "Xautoconf" \
            -a "X" != "Xreconfig"; then \
        GUI_INC_LOC="" GUI_LIB_LOC="" \
            CC="" CPPFLAGS="" CFLAGS="" \
            LDFLAGS=""  srcdir="." \
            ./configure    \
              \
               \
               \
               \
               \
              \
               \
             \
               \
              \
            ; \
    fi
"X" was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [auto/config.mk] Error 255
```

I got this when I ran make in just `vim/`

```
! was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [first] Error 255
```

Also, I'm using MobaXTerm, which came with Vim 7.3

Using the built in installer does not work as well.

```
mobapt

Updating packages list, please wait...
Installing  vim

/bin/apt-cyg   install  vim
Found package vim
Downloading vim-8.0.0494-1.tar.xz...
Downloading /home/mobaxterm/.aptcyg/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.kernel.org%2fsourceware%2fcygwin/release/vim/vim-8.0.0494-1.tar.xz using Windows internet settings
sha512sum: can't open 'vim-8.0.0494-1.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 476: test: 66691247e5715e05e96098f47174b13d7e0ab3027f1c3f0c325ee24804f9d72c64c617fbecf4f3fe8d8ca41ebc09ba67b82a62a0c7bd25f0c763f0236bc13751: unary operator expected
md5sum: can't open 'vim-8.0.0494-1.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 479: test: 66691247e5715e05e96098f47174b13d7e0ab3027f1c3f0c325ee24804f9d72c64c617fbecf4f3fe8d8ca41ebc09ba67b82a62a0c7bd25f0c763f0236bc13751: unary operator expected
Checksum did not match, exiting
```

Comment: MobaXTerm seems to be coming up a lot these days so I went to their site and it appears to use [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) under the hood, which has [a very recent Vim](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/vim/) available so… why don't you use that?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to with the link you posted. The links on that page don't let you download anything

Comment: Who said anything about downloading? The MobaXterm site claims it has a built-in package manager, did you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `configure` script under src. You need to run it before running `make`.

The `configure` script creates `config.mk` file which is used by `make`.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It gave me this error `no terminal library found` so I tried to install ncurses and reran the configure script with `--with-tlib=ncursesw` but it also didn't work

Comment: Honestly I'm just going to switch back to Cygwin. The devs of MobaXTerm claim that it's a newer and much better version of Cygwin but I've had way too much trouble trying to install stuff and resolve dependencies. The GUI aspect of the app is nice, but they should just package up all of these dependencies and make sure their built in installation feature works `mobapt`